# How to call move right or left in Waterwheel Carousel using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to jquery and I want to move my Waterwheel Carouselc  **left /right**  from buttons

suppose I have a button for right movement How can I do this code using Waterwheel Carousel function?
I have tried the following code :

```
$("#waterwheelcarouseldefault").waterwheelCarousel().moveItem();
```

any one has a code for it ?

Comment: @roasted ofcourse $("#waterwheelcarouseldefault").waterwheelCarousel().moveItem();

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to move carousel item when click a button?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14338904/how-to-move-carousel-item-when-click-a-button)

Answer (score 0):

in left button write this :

```
$("#waterwheelcarouseldefault").find('.carousel-controls .carousel-prev').trigger('click');
```

in right button write this :

```
$("#waterwheelcarouseldefault").find('.carousel-controls .carousel-next').trigger('click');
```

I think this might be work.