# How to move carousel item when click a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am working with [waterwheel carousel](http://code.google.com/p/proyectofinalingles/source/browse/trunk/js/jquery.waterwheelCarousel.js?r=19) I want to call move function based on my button click

here is my code :

```
 function myFunction()
{
 $("#waterwheel-carousel-default").waterwheelCarousel().moveOnce(true);
}
```

It's give me an error

> TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$("#waterwheel-carousel-default").waterwheelCarousel().

Any one can help?

Comment: Do you get the error when trying to initialize the plugin normally, or only inside your click function? It looks like `$("#waterwheel-carousel-default").waterwheelCarousel` is `undefined`, so are you sure you're including the javascript file correctly? Even without the error, though, I don't think you'll be able to call `moveOnce`, as it's an inner function of the plugin, not a member of the return value.

Comment: @freejosh It is initialize correctly but how can I call **moveonce,** method

Comment: Ah, so the `undefined` error is probably referring to `moveOnce` since, like I said, it's not in the return value. Ahmed Assaf's answer below is probably the only way - use your function to find the default button and trigger its `click`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In left button write this :

```
$("#waterwheel-carousel-default").find('.carousel-controls .carousel-prev').trigger('click');
```

In right button write this :

```
$("#waterwheel-carousel-default").find('.carousel-controls .carousel-next').trigger('click');
```

Try this.